# Jsoup not parsing specific tags

Tags: java, android, xml, jsoup

I'm parsing xml file, selecting text between  tags. Everything parsing okay, except one item. Here's a piece of xml:

```
    <ipb>
    <categories>
    <category>
    <id>13</id>
    <name>ARSENAL FC</name>
    <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=13</url>
    <forums>
    <forum>...</forum>
    <forum>
    <id>36</id>

    <name>DOWNLOAD</name>

    <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=36</url>
    <description>...</description>
    <type>1</type>
    <topics>21</topics>
    <replies>1 236</replies>
    <lastpost>
    <date>27 Сентябрь 2012 - 18:22</date>
    <name>ВИДЕО-сезон-2012/13</name>
    <id>2680</id>
    <url>
     http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showtopic=2680&view=getlastpost
     </url>
     <user>
     <id>6455</id>
      <name>mArt_</name>
      <url>
       http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showuser=6455
        </url>
       </user>
     </lastpost>
       </forum>
```

Everything selects fine, except

```
<name>DOWNLOAD</name>
```

This is selecting text in  tags.

```
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(changeLinkToXml(arg0[0])).get(); //getting xml file
        Elements forums = doc.select("name:contains(ARSENAL FC)~forums>forum");
        forumNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Element element:forums){
            forumNames.add(element.getElementsByTag("name").first().text());
        }
        Log.i("forums", forumNames.toString());
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

and for sure, output for  Log.i("forums", forumNames.toString()):

```
INFO/forums(12014): [Gunners, Premier League, FA Cup, Carling Cup, UEFA Champions League, Трансферы, Арсенальский офф-топ]
```

No DOWNLOAD string here.

EDIT: posting full xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ipb>

        <categories>


            <category>
                <id>13</id>
                <name>ARSENAL FC</name>
                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=13</url>
                <forums>

                    <forum>
                        <id>1</id>
                        <name>Gunners</name>
                        <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=1</url>
                        <description><![CDATA[все о канонирах: героях настоящего времени, прошлого и будущего]]></description>
                            <type>1</type>
                        <topics>204</topics>
                        <replies>65 812</replies>
                        <lastpost>
                                <date>Сегодня, 15:01</date>
                            <name>Лучший игрок сентября. Сезо...</name>
                            <id>2732</id>
                            <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showtopic=2732&amp;view=getlastpost</url>
                            <user>

                                <id>35318</id>
                                <name>Podolski</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showuser=35318</url>                                     

                            </user>
                        </lastpost>                 

                        <subforums>

                            <subforum>
                                <id>19</id>
                                <name>Игрок месяца</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>32</id>
                                <name>ex-gunners</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>

                        </subforums>

                    </forum>


                    <forum>
                        <id>2</id>
                        <name>Premier League</name>
                        <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=2</url>
                        <description><![CDATA[английская Премьер Лига. Размышления и обзоры матчей]]></description>
                            <type>1</type>
                        <topics>330</topics>
                        <replies>77 165</replies>
                        <lastpost>
                                <date>10 Октябрь 2012 - 13:12</date>
                            <name>West Ham - ARSENAL</name>
                            <id>2730</id>
                            <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showtopic=2730&amp;view=getlastpost</url>
                            <user>

                                <id>33744</id>
                                <name>bartlby</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showuser=33744</url>                                     

                            </user>
                        </lastpost>                 

                        <subforums>

                            <subforum>
                                <id>67</id>
                                <name>Сезон 2011/12</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>60</id>
                                <name>Сезон 2010/11</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>57</id>
                                <name>Сезон 2009/10</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>37</id>
                                <name>Сезон 2008/09</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>34</id>
                                <name>Сезон 2007/08</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>25</id>
                                <name>Сезон 2006/07</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>26</id>
                                <name>Сезон 2005/06</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>27</id>
                                <name>Сезон 2004/05</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>28</id>
                                <name>Сезон 2003/04</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>

                        </subforums>

                    </forum>


                    <forum>
                        <id>3</id>
                        <name>FA Cup, Carling Cup</name>
                        <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=3</url>
                        <description><![CDATA[самый старый футбольный трофей мира, а также Carling Cup (Кубок Лиги). Размышления и обзоры матчей]]></description>
                            <type>1</type>
                        <topics>73</topics>
                        <replies>14 211</replies>
                        <lastpost>
                                <date>29 Сентябрь 2012 - 02:39</date>
                            <name>ARSENAL - Coventry City</name>
                            <id>2721</id>
                            <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showtopic=2721&amp;view=getlastpost</url>
                            <user>

                                <id>1163</id>
                                <name>miidi</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showuser=1163</url>                                      

                            </user>
                        </lastpost>                 

                        <subforums>

                            <subforum>
                                <id>68</id>
                                <name>Сезон 2011/12</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>61</id>
                                <name>Сезон 2010/11</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>58</id>
                                <name>Сезон 2009/10</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>38</id>
                                <name>Сезон 2008/09</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>33</id>
                                <name>Сезон 2007/08</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>21</id>
                                <name>Сезон 2006/07</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>22</id>
                                <name>Сезон 2005/06</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>23</id>
                                <name>Сезон 2004/05</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>24</id>
                                <name>Сезон 2003/04</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>

                        </subforums>

                    </forum>


                    <forum>
                        <id>4</id>
                        <name>UEFA Champions League</name>
                        <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=4</url>
                        <description><![CDATA[Лига Европейских Чемпионов. Размышления и обзоры матчей]]></description>
                            <type>1</type>
                        <topics>112</topics>
                        <replies>28 686</replies>
                        <lastpost>
                                <date>05 Октябрь 2012 - 20:16</date>
                            <name>ARSENAL - Olympiacos</name>
                            <id>2728</id>
                            <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showtopic=2728&amp;view=getlastpost</url>
                            <user>

                                <id>7062</id>
                                <name>H.A.L.O.</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showuser=7062</url>                                      

                            </user>
                        </lastpost>                 

                        <subforums>

                            <subforum>
                                <id>69</id>
                                <name>Сезон 2011/12</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>62</id>
                                <name>Сезон 2010/11</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>59</id>
                                <name>Сезон 2009/10</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>39</id>
                                <name>Сезон 2008/09</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>35</id>
                                <name>Сезон 2007/08</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>29</id>
                                <name>Сезон 2006/07</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>30</id>
                                <name>Сезон 2005/06</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>31</id>
                                <name>Сезон 2004/05</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>

                        </subforums>

                    </forum>


                    <forum>
                        <id>36</id>
                        <name>DOWNLOAD</name>
                        <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=36</url>
                        <description><![CDATA[видео, фото, аудио]]></description>
                            <type>1</type>
                        <topics>21</topics>
                        <replies>1 236</replies>
                        <lastpost>
                                <date>27 Сентябрь 2012 - 18:22</date>
                            <name>ВИДЕО-сезон-2012/13</name>
                            <id>2680</id>
                            <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showtopic=2680&amp;view=getlastpost</url>
                            <user>

                                <id>6455</id>
                                <name>mArt_</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showuser=6455</url>                                      

                            </user>
                        </lastpost>                 

                    </forum>


                    <forum>
                        <id>7</id>
                        <name>Трансферы</name>
                        <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=7</url>
                        <description><![CDATA[реальные покупки и трансферные "утки"]]></description>
                            <type>1</type>
                        <topics>39</topics>
                        <replies>40 030</replies>
                        <lastpost>
                                <date>Вчера, 08:34</date>
                            <name>Какого игрока я бы хотел ви...</name>
                            <id>787</id>
                            <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showtopic=787&amp;view=getlastpost</url>
                            <user>

                                <id>33744</id>
                                <name>bartlby</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showuser=33744</url>                                     

                            </user>
                        </lastpost>                 

                    </forum>


                    <forum>
                        <id>10</id>
                        <name>Арсенальский офф-топ</name>
                        <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=10</url>
                        <description><![CDATA[околоклубный офф-топ, не относящийся к другим темам]]></description>
                            <type>1</type>
                        <topics>151</topics>
                        <replies>26 000</replies>
                        <lastpost>
                                <date>Сегодня, 09:55</date>
                            <name>Статистика+Анализ</name>
                            <id>2309</id>
                            <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showtopic=2309&amp;view=getlastpost</url>
                            <user>

                                <id>1085</id>
                                <name>House M.D.</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showuser=1085</url>                                      

                            </user>
                        </lastpost>                 

                    </forum>

                </forums>
            </category>




            <category>
                <id>14</id>
                <name>ARSSC</name>
                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=14</url>
                <forums>

                    <forum>
                        <id>5</id>
                        <name>ARSSC</name>
                        <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=5</url>
                        <description><![CDATA[Arsenal Russian Speaking Supporters Club. Жизнь фан-клуба]]></description>
                            <type>1</type>
                        <topics>240</topics>
                        <replies>49 238</replies>
                        <lastpost>
                                <date>Сегодня, 15:16</date>
                            <name>офф-топ</name>
                            <id>2515</id>
                            <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showtopic=2515&amp;view=getlastpost</url>
                            <user>

                                <id>22995</id>
                                <name>LeXuS R.</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showuser=22995</url>                                     

                            </user>
                        </lastpost>                 

                        <subforums>

                            <subforum>
                                <id>56</id>
                                <name>10-летие ARSSC</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>45</id>
                                <name>Белорусское отделение</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>48</id>
                                <name>Московское отделение</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>49</id>
                                <name>Питерское отделение</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>46</id>
                                <name>Урало-Сибирское отделение</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>47</id>
                                <name>Украинское отделение</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>40</id>
                                <name>Выезды ARSSC</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>41</id>
                                <name>Футбольный клуб ARSSC</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>42</id>
                                <name>Хочу в ARSSC</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>43</id>
                                <name>Проекты ARSSC</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>50</id>
                                <name>Нижегородское отделение</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>51</id>
                                <name>Казахстанское отделение</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>52</id>
                                <name>Тбилисское отделение</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>53</id>
                                <name>Кыргызстано-Бишкекское отделение</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>

                        </subforums>

                    </forum>


                    <forum>
                        <id>11</id>
                        <name>==ARSSC==</name>
                        <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=11</url>
                        <description><![CDATA[только для участников ARSSC]]></description>
                            <type>1</type>
                        <topics>79</topics>
                        <replies>6 429</replies>
                        <lastpost>
                                <date>30 Сентябрь 2012 - 23:16</date>
                            <name>Важно! Сбор данных членов Ф...</name>
                            <id>2684</id>
                            <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showtopic=2684&amp;view=getlastpost</url>
                            <user>

                                <id>34</id>
                                <name>Blader</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showuser=34</url>                                        

                            </user>
                        </lastpost>                 

                    </forum>


                    <forum>
                        <id>8</id>
                        <name>Форум и сайт</name>
                        <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=8</url>
                        <description><![CDATA[все вопросы по форуму и сайту FC-Arsenal.com]]></description>
                            <type>1</type>
                        <topics>63</topics>
                        <replies>8 978</replies>
                        <lastpost>
                                <date>12 Октябрь 2012 - 23:24</date>
                            <name>Как сделать жисть лучше и и...</name>
                            <id>1164</id>
                            <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showtopic=1164&amp;view=getlastpost</url>
                            <user>

                                <id>2741</id>
                                <name>Mozart23</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showuser=2741</url>                                      

                            </user>
                        </lastpost>                 

                        <subforums>

                            <subforum>
                                <id>44</id>
                                <name>FC-Arsenal.com</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>55</id>
                                <name>Модернизация форума</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>65</id>
                                <name>Обсуждение действий модераторов</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>

                        </subforums>

                    </forum>

                </forums>
            </category>




            <category>
                <id>15</id>
                <name>OFF-TOP</name>
                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=15</url>
                <forums>

                    <forum>
                        <id>6</id>
                        <name>Футбольный офф-топ</name>
                        <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=6</url>
                        <description><![CDATA[все о футбольном офф-топе, не относящееся к Арсеналу]]></description>
                            <type>1</type>
                        <topics>189</topics>
                        <replies>30 210</replies>
                        <lastpost>
                                <date>14 Октябрь 2012 - 17:34</date>
                            <name>Кубки Африканских Наций</name>
                            <id>2518</id>
                            <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showtopic=2518&amp;view=getlastpost</url>
                            <user>

                                <id>23982</id>
                                <name>sanchouz</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showuser=23982</url>                                     

                            </user>
                        </lastpost>                 

                    </forum>


                    <forum>
                        <id>9</id>
                        <name>Полный офф-топ</name>
                        <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=9</url>
                        <description><![CDATA[офф-топ вне футбола]]></description>
                            <type>1</type>
                        <topics>110</topics>
                        <replies>42 353</replies>
                        <lastpost>
                                <date>Сегодня, 15:29</date>
                            <name>Фильмы</name>
                            <id>145</id>
                            <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showtopic=145&amp;view=getlastpost</url>
                            <user>

                                <id>24</id>
                                <name>kust</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showuser=24</url>                                        

                            </user>
                        </lastpost>                 

                    </forum>


                    <forum>
                        <id>12</id>
                        <name>Прогнозы</name>
                        <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=12</url>
                        <description><![CDATA[чемпионат по прогнозам]]></description>
                            <type>1</type>
                        <topics>278</topics>
                        <replies>7 093</replies>
                        <lastpost>
                                <date>18 Сентябрь 2012 - 00:27</date>
                            <name>Fantasy and Predictor 2012/...</name>
                            <id>2683</id>
                            <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showtopic=2683&amp;view=getlastpost</url>
                            <user>

                                <id>32662</id>
                                <name>olegkorben</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showuser=32662</url>                                     

                            </user>
                        </lastpost>                 

                        <subforums>

                            <subforum>
                                <id>17</id>
                                <name>архив: 2004/05</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>18</id>
                                <name>архив: 2005/06</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>20</id>
                                <name>архив: 2006/07</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>63</id>
                                <name>архив: 2008/09</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>


                            <subforum>
                                <id>64</id>
                                <name>Fantasy premier league 2011/2012</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=</url>
                            </subforum>

                        </subforums>

                    </forum>


                    <forum>
                        <id>66</id>
                        <name>Песочница</name>
                        <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showforum=66</url>
                        <description><![CDATA[рассказываем о себе]]></description>
                            <type>1</type>
                        <topics>90</topics>
                        <replies>1 339</replies>
                        <lastpost>
                                <date>06 Октябрь 2012 - 21:50</date>
                            <name>serg1945</name>
                            <id>2729</id>
                            <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showtopic=2729&amp;view=getlastpost</url>
                            <user>

                                <id>13040</id>
                                <name>FoLL</name>
                                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showuser=13040</url>                                     

                            </user>
                        </lastpost>                 

                    </forum>

                </forums>
            </category>


        </categories>

        <statistics>
            <posts>402 255</posts>
            <members>6 585</members>
            <user>
                <id></id>
                <name>klimistwood</name>
                <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showuser=36016</url>
            </user>
            <onlinerecord>152</onlinerecord>
        </statistics>

        <events>



        </events>
        <birthdays>

            <total>3</total>
            <users><birthday>
    <year>30</year>
    <user>
        <id>1081</id>
        <name>TremoR</name>
        <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showuser=1081</url>      
    </user>
</birthday>,<birthday>
    <year>30</year>
    <user>
        <id>32816</id>
        <name>ArseR</name>
        <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showuser=32816</url>     
    </user>
</birthday>,<birthday>
    <year>22</year>
    <user>
        <id>27408</id>
        <name>ArsoFanLV</name>
        <url>http://www.fc-arsenal.com/ipb/xml.php?showuser=27408</url>     
    </user>
</birthday></users>

        </birthdays>
</ipb>
```

here's a link to it http://pastebin.com/fM2LUNeA

Comment: The same happenned to me in another place of my program. Not parsing another part of xml file. But other parts on the same levels parsing okay. Just as above. Sorry for such delay, visited this page everyday, haven't noticed your commentary.

Comment: When parsing XML you should set an XML parser [Connection#parser(Parser.xmlParser())](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#parser(org.jsoup.parser.Parser)). I haven't tried it for your problem, but as `name` is a common attribute in HTML it could lead to problems.

Comment: changed `doc = Jsoup.connect(changeLinkToXml(arg0[0])).get();`  to `doc = Jsoup.connect(changeLinkToXml(arg0[0])).parser(Parser.xmlParser()).get();` nothing changed

Comment: which version of Jsoup are you using ? cos this is working just fine for me brother. i'm using Jsoup 1.6.3

Comment: hm, it's very strange. i'm using 1.7.1. Just tested with 1.6.3. No changes. It seems i'll have to change my xml parser. I'm still got no ideas what's wrong with the code

Comment: By the way why are you using JSoup to parse XML? There are dedicated XML parsers, and the Android API provides XML parsing capabilities itself.

Comment: In my project, i'm parsing not only xml-files. So i decided not to change the tool. But now it seems, i'll have to do it. Have no time to test other xml-parsers now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
//Load into Jsoup
Element root = Jsoup.parse(Runner.class.getResourceAsStream("/sources"), "utf-8", "");   
Elements names = root.select("ipb > categories > category > name:contains(ARSENAL FC) ~forums > forum > name");
System.out.println(names);
```

And watch your JSoup version, should grab the latest one, I aware some selecting syntax problems before.